# Error response from daemon: pull access denied for universal, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

For context, I have been spending this week getting up a Docker test environment up for our inhouse job tracking software. I have been following the instructions left by the previous developer, but have been running into issues when trying to compose my containers. The first error was an TSL Handshake error that was resolved when I was whitelisted on our corporate WSA.
After the WSA issue was resolved, my error has changed to this.

```
C:\Users\bjp\Documents\Work\universal>docker-compose up -d
[+] Running 0/1
 - universal Error                                                                                                                                                                2.0s
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for universal, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

For more context, the images were built, the tracker software was properly cloned into the correct directory, the software has its own config files set for testing, and there is the yaml docker-compose file right in the root universal file directory.

I've been trouble shooting this for days thanks to help of folks on here, and several other forums. I'm feeling really close here. I could use the assistance to get across the finish line, so I can start developing.

Thanks!

Comment: Most likely either the repository does not exist, or you are not authenticated to the registry.  Can you provide any more details about the name of your image and where it is hosted?

Comment: Sure thing! So the universal image is in a build folder inside my main universal directory: C:\Users\bjp\Documents\Work\universal\build 

The image is called "stretch.universal"

Comment: What image is being used in the docker-compose service?  It seems like you are trying to use the image name `universal` when it should really be `stretch.universal`.  Can you share some information about your compose file?

Comment: Dude, you just saved me! It's running! So for clarification, when I built my universal image, it was labeled universal:stretch, but the docker-compose config file was looking for an image labeled universal:current. 

I have no idea why they had different names. I should really familiarize myself more with what exactly docker did as it built the image I needed.

Answer (score 0):

My docker compose file was looking for universal:stretch, but the actual universal image was labeled universal:current.

Note that the code was working for the previous web dev at our company, so I'm assuming an older version of Docker allowed "current" to be used as a generic filler term?

I'm not 100% sure, nut I fixed this issue by making sure all of my labels were matching in my compose and image files.